# Text that is absolute positioned to the bottom of a div needs to grow/expand down instead of up

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a three column layout that positions the Calls to action at the bottom using absolute positioning and a height of 100% on the container:

```
-----------------------------    -----------------------------     -----------------------------  
| Col 1                     |    | Col 2                     |     | Col 3                     |
|                           |    |                           |     |                           |
| Copy                      |    | Copy                      |     | Copy                      |
|                           |    |                           |     |                           |
|                           |    |                           |     | Call to action 3 is       |
| Call to action 1          |    | Call to action 2          |     | Longer text               |
-----------------------------    -----------------------------     -----------------------------
```

But what I want is for the first sentence in the paragraph to be even with the others, even if the rest overflows outside the container:

```
-----------------------------    -----------------------------     -----------------------------  
| Col 1                     |    | Col 2                     |     | Col 3                     |
|                           |    |                           |     |                           |
| Copy                      |    | Copy                      |     | Copy                      |
|                           |    |                           |     |                           |
|                           |    |                           |     |                           |
| Call to action 1          |    | Call to action 2          |     | Call to action 3 is       |
-----------------------------    -----------------------------     -----------------------------  
                                                                     Longer text
```

I was able to accomplish this by using top:300px instead of bottom:10px on the CTAs, but this isn't ideal because you can't change the # of characters in the copy without adjusting the top:300px value.   Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Position them from `top`, but use `calc(100% - 10px)` instead? (Or however much you want to be shown of the element instead of 10px; maybe even use a more suitable unit for the second value, like em, for less problems with relative font sizes.)

Comment: I would use `calc(100vh - 10px)` instead because 100% can mean anything, really.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this by pushing the CTA completely out of the card and then using a transform value equal to your line-height to pull it back up.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 2.2em;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

.cta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0 1em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-1.2em);
  /* line-height */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, voluptatem.</p>
    <div class="cta">CTA</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate repellendus in magni?</p>
    <div class="cta">CTA Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Heading 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <div class="cta">CTA Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Paulie_D's idea may also work, but 04FS's solution to use top:calc(100% - 10px) instead of bottom worked like a charm! Thanks